# Android Volley ImageLoader return wrong oriented bitmap

Tags: android, image, android-volley, image-caching

I am using volley's image caching through ImageLoader

```
mImageLoader.get(vehicleInfo.getUserInfo().getProfileImage(), new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer imageContainer, boolean b) {
                    if (imageContainer.getBitmap() != null) {
                        ivUserImage.setImageBitmap(imageContainer.getBitmap());
                    }
                }
```

with url 
https://vehicollate-dev.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/uploadVehicles/102/102_PB08BT0402.png

image orientation is portrait but it imageview shows landscape.

Comment: That PNG file seems corrupt; leastways, I cannot successfully open it.

Comment: @CommonsWare url updated